# Chargify Product Price update via api or code

Tags: php, drupal, chargify

I am using Chargify API for payment. and I have created some products there for subscription. Now I want to manage those Products price and other settings via my site admin panel. But I not find any function or any way in Chargify API. If any one know any way to update this via api or via code ,please tell me.

thanks in advance to all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem you can change the price of an existing product (which seems very strange), only create new ones. [Source](http://docs.chargify.com/api-products).

You can however [make adjustments to existing subscriptions](http://docs.chargify.com/api-adjustments).

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to bring this back, but I had the same issue and in my tests (currently) I was able to update products making a PUT request.

The **PUT** request must be sent to the following url:

```
http://<site>.chargify.com/products/<product_id>
```

And send in the body only the fields that needs to be updated.

Example:

```
PUT https://mysite.chargify.com/products/7358179 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Authorization: <your authorization token>
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: mysite.chargify.com
Content-Length: 106

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<product>
    <price_in_cents>2100</price_in_cents>
</product>
```

Hope this helps other users that find this page using search engines like I did.